# A special case of zero simultaneity bias?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

Consider a system of structural equations,
$$
Y=\alpha _{0}+\alpha _{1}X_{1}+\alpha _{2}X_{2}+\varepsilon:=X\alpha+\varepsilon\\
X_1=\pi _{0,1}+\pi _{1,1}Y+\eta _{1}\\
X_2=\pi _{0,2}+\pi _{1,2}Y+\eta _{2},
$$
where the errors $\varepsilon,\eta_1,\eta_2$ are all mean zero and uncorrelated. Think of $X_1,X_2$ as optimal responses to $Y$ while at the same time affecting $Y$.

In general, when fitting the first equation,
$$
\hat{\alpha}=\alpha+\delta,
$$
where
$$
\delta=(X'X)^{-1}X'\varepsilon,
$$
so the $\delta$ coefficients stem from a projection of $\varepsilon$ on the $X$ space.

My question is this: Is there a conceivable situation where, say, $\delta_1\neq0,\delta_2=0$ while $\pi_{1,1}\neq0,\pi_{1,2}\neq0$?

Perhaps one could find expressions for $E[X'X]$ and $E[X'\varepsilon]$ from the corresponding reduced form equations, and construct a numerical example with or without intuitive appeal.

However, having in mind the interpretations of the slope coefficients in the model, is there an intuitive situation where $X_2$ has a zero coefficient in the projection of $\varepsilon$ on $X$, while $\pi_{1,2}\neq0$? In other words, could the realization of $\varepsilon$ elicit a response in both variables, while the partial correlation between $\varepsilon$ and $X_2$ after netting out $X_1$ is zero? In this case, one could possibly think of $X_1$ and $X_2$ as a "primary" and a "secondary" choice variable. Or is this impossible from the start?